# Fredhopper Indexer's qserver instance consuming too much CPU

Tags: fredhopper, query

Preview page is loading within **1.7 mins**, FH query took **6.084 secs** and QServer consumes more than **%95 CPU**. This as a blocker problem, results in slowing down the whole system. Is there any way of identifying the problem and the reason why it cannot get any better ?

I am using the indexer for both indexer and qserver instances.

The actions I've taken and did not help are;

1. Increasing qserver memory of indexer from 1500 to 6000; 
   instance3_qserver_memory=6000
2. [We started the procedure of reindexing](https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Recreating+an+instance) . 
   We stopped the index server , took a backup of fredhopper with ; 
   `bin/capture-import <INSTANCE> path/to/capture.zip`

   We copied all of the files in

   `<BASE_DIRECTORY>\INDEXER>\data\xml\processed\batch; into 
    <BASE_DIRECTORY>\<INDEXER>\data\fas-xml\<CATALOG01> .`

   We ran the "reindexer" with; 
   `bin/reindex indexer` command.

   And also run the following command to update the configured live servers with
   the current index and configuration; 
   `bin\fresh-index-to-live indexer`
3. We observed that the items are being indexed, and the
   number of items being indexed is being counted down. When there is no item left to index, then I restarted the qserver of indexer with the following command.

`bin\deployment-agent-client --location localhost invoke <INDEXER> qserver stop
 bin\deployment-agent-client --location localhost invoke <INDEXER> qserver start`

4. None helped. Each time I check the processes, Dapp-name=qserver  instance consuming too much CPU up to 350%. I observed the kitchen, indexer instance logs,  Fredhopper.log and qserver.log files.  What I see is the following (I doubt they cause to excessive amount of CPU usage),

**qserver.log files**
"http-nio-10180-exec-39" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000xxxxxxx nid=0x4e27 runnable [0x00007fb8909eaxxx]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007e1280xxx> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

**fredhopper.log**
2016-01-05 17:58:43,834 WARN  [http-nio-10181-exec-32] SortFieldFilter.java:38 50180 Removing the field 'pubtitle' from the sort fields. Sorting on non-live attributes is not supported. Please include this field in the tree attributes in order to sort on it. || fredhopper@hostName:fredhopper/data/installations/FAS tags/fas/fas-7.5.0.16/engine@107262 - url: http://{url}

**Since it states that "Sorting on non-live attributes is not supported." , I go to the Business manager and checked the pubtitle attribute if it is live or not. And I confirm it is live . So why is it throwing such SortFieldFilter WARN, no clue !**

**EDIT** : The exception I gave in qserver.log, is thrown thousands of times; could the excessive usage of CPU be caused by this problem  ?

[There is an entry regarding the exception;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389403/how-to-interpret-a-java-thread-stack)

**EDIT 2:  I also checked the CPU usage in SIT, and observed that its behaviour in terms of CPU usage is similar to the UAT's .  In another word, overall CPU usage is up to 80%, and qserver instance's CPU usage is around 250%. So, there is a similar behaviour, but SIT can handle the operations with no problem. At least for now.**

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying it continues to use CPU power, even though there is no work left to be done? That would be very strange.

Answer (score -1):

Did you analyze your relevant code and ensure there is no scope of memory leak?

May be you can try replicating the environment on a separate server - may be Dev and try reproducing the scenario there. Further you can remove all possible integration points to the fredhopper server and try checking with simple queries on it.

I hope it may help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pankaj. Answer to your question is yes. I also have the same settings on DEV and SIT .  No problem occurs. Thus, I doubt that it is related to the code.  But in UAT, I have this kind of problem.  Can you please lead me to a tutorial explaining how to remove all possible integration points to the fredhopper server?  I am quite unsure what it means actually.

Comment: I simply meant to say, comment out all your code making a connection or query to Fredhopper and then try with very simple query...and then starts eabling your code a chunk by chunk to identify a possibly problematic code

Comment: I see, but the thing is that the same logic , and block of codes are available in other environments working just fine. Thus, let me keep this option as the last one.